# Какую технологию актуально использовать для верстки сайтов?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Какую технологию актуально использовать на сегодняшний день, для верстки, как адаптивных сайтов (плавное изменение размера div), так и сайтов в фиксированной шириной страниц,которые изменяют свою ширину, по точечно(то есть в заранее выставленных рамках)?

**Варианты:**

**1.**http://960.gs/ (Но тут почему то не работает адаптивный дизайн, там все фиксировано Размеры **не** устанавливаются от %)

**2.**http://www.blueprintcss.org/ (еще не пробовал, что скажите?)

**3.**http://materializecss.com/grid.html (пробовал, вроде ничего так, для адаптивных сайтов не плохо как по мне)

**4.**http://onepcssgrid.mattimling.com/ (не пробовал)

Что **порекомендуете** из вышеперечисленного, или может быть **приложите свой вариант**?

Comment: bootstrap (если нужно, можно использовать только сетку) + препроцессоцы css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap. Плюсы:

- имеются собственные базовые стили, которые хорошо выглядят
- возможность адаптации под мобильные устройства
- распространенность: больше вероятности найти ответ на возникающий вопрос.
- модульность: необязательно тащить все технологии на сайт, можно выбрать необходимое

Comment: Почему не флекс боксы? они очень гибкие. А с прекращением поддержки IE 8-10 так вообще супер вариант для всего. Уже два года ими пользуюсь. Есть свои пару нюансов, но, думаю, поправят.

Comment: а у bootstrap минусы -почему не описали ? то что сначала надо всю их вёрстку изучить , а потом писать уже